# When is a while(True) loop appropriate?

Tags: while-loop, conditional-statements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is while(true) bad programming practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390481/is-whiletrue-bad-programming-practice)
>   [What's the point of using “while (true) {…}”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947055/whats-the-point-of-using-while-true)

I've always considered it bad practice to use `while(true)`. Many people think it's okay.

Why would you want to purposefully create an infinite loop? The only two reasons I can think of are:

1. You're being devious
2. You're being lazy

When, if ever, is it appropriate to use this? And why would you use this over an algorithm?

Comment: "why would you use this over an algorithm": Umm... you can use it as *part* of an algorithm. The two aren't mutually exclusive.

Comment: I'm asking when it's appropriate..not whether it is bad or not - just reasons for why exactly it could be used.

Comment: @DoctorOreo Judge the worth of an resolved question by it's answers not by the title.

Comment: BTW, it's not called "being lazy" , it's called saving time for sleep!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes, `while(true)` is more readable than the alternatives. Case in point:

```
BufferedReader in = ...;
while (true)
{
  String line = in.readLine();
  if (line == null)
    break;
  process(line);
}
```

Consider the alternative:

```
BufferedReader in = ...;
String line;
while ((line = in.readLine) != null)
  process(line);
```

Answer (score 1):

- In threaded code (concurrent programming)..
- In games and for menus
- While using C or Fortran(I mean moreso here)

Actually you see it a lot...

Comment: Isn't "While using C or Fortran" a bit... general...

Comment: ;) yes I was being facetious a bit. I'm reminded of network programming in C , for some reason.