# Is there any real use of the forever keyword in Qt?

Tags: qt, for-loop

I recently learned that Qt provides a `forever` keyword which allows you to enter in an infinite iteration loop. Is there any real life situation where one would want to do that? Isn't it always better practice to use `foreach`?

Comment: It can be useful when you poll something on a second thread.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: Semantically I think your asking the same as [What's the point of using “while (true) {…}”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947055/whats-the-point-of-using-while-true)

Comment: @NewEyes > Sometimes, you want to check for a value being changed (such as temperature). You can then have an infinite loop that looks for a change and update a view. Alex K. comment should help you, too.